# How to fill the small hole of the binary image using opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have binary image, the image have many samll black-hole, I want to fill the hole so that I can get the object contours, but the `cv.dilate` method work not very well, can someone have good method do that?

**The Image**
[image]

**Need to fill the object like this(sample)**
[image]

Comment: source data is required. some things should not be fixed but prevented from happening. also review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Next time I will post the origin data, Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try applying **iterative** morphological operations (`Erode` + `Dilate`). this should join the white blobs while preserving their size. Get the external `contours` and then just compute their `bounding boxes`. Depending on your original input (not the binary mask you posted) some tweaks could be made. Let's work with that binary image, this is the code:

```
# Imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "9ZL1r.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Deep Copy:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# (Otsu) Threshold:
thresh, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Apply Dilate + Erode:
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=5)
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=5)
```

So far I've only read, thresholded and filtered the input image. This is the filtered result:

[image]

Looks good. Let's get the bounding rectangles:

```
# Find the EXTERNAL contours on the binary image:
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Look for the outer bounding boxes (no children):
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get the bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Draw the rectangle on the input image:
    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # (Optional) Set color and draw:
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.rectangle(inputImageCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                  (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2)

    # Show image:
    cv2.imshow("Bounding Rectangles", inputImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Pls let me give you a red rose, Thanks for you help。